# How can I draw a table like this one In LaTex?

Tags: tables

It has been a while without using Latex, my wish is to reproduce a table like the one attached below. How can I make it?

```
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \capthe tion{Resource analysis for proposed compiler.}
      \begin{tabular}{lSSSSSS}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{n-qubits} &
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total gates} &
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{Depth steps} \\
          & {State Generation} & {QFT} & {StateGeneration} & {QFT} &  \\
          \midrule
        2 & 7 & 11 & 5 & 9 \\
        4 & 13 & 42 & 7 & 25 \\
        6 & 19 & 93 & 9 & 41 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code gives the following table
[image]

What I want is to reproduce this one
[image]

Comment: Please, show us, what you try so far. Basic, how to write  tables you find in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tabularray` package we get the following table. Is that you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering,singlelinecheck=no]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering\caption{Resource analysis for proposed compiler.}
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]Q[c]},rows={m,0.8cm},cell{1}{1}={r=2,c=1}{l},hline{2}={3}{solid,rightpos=-1}}
            \toprule
            n-qubits & Total gates &  & Depth steps &  \\
            \cmidrule[l=-1]{2,3} \cmidrule[lr=-1]{4}
            & {State Generation} & {QFT} & {StateGeneration} & {QFT}  \\
            \midrule
            2 & 7 & 11 & 5 & 9 \\
            4 & 13 & 42 & 7 & 25 \\
            6 & 19 & 93 & 9 & 41 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your possible solution on this, I want to ask about the midline that separates Total gates and the State generation. How can I adjust so that it can reach the column with QFT

Comment: @Kimwaga makono. As it is it just reach the column of QFT if you draw all hlines and vlines you can see it. You just want it a little bigger but not crossing the column of QFT or want it to join with the other line separates Debth Steps and State generation? Both can be done.

Comment: It should start at S for State generation to T for QFT

Comment: @Kimwaga makono: I modified the code the way to help you achieve what you want. Please check it out and the new output. Do you need this for the next two columns also?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just edited `\cmidrule[lr=-1]{4}` to `\cmidrule[lr=-1]{4,5}`